# using python to search extremely large text file

Tags: python, search, large-data

I have a large 40 million line, 3 gigabyte text file (probably wont be able to fit in memory) in the following format:

```
399.4540176 {Some other data}
404.498759292 {Some other data}
408.362737492 {Some other data}
412.832976111 {Some other data}
415.70665675 {Some other data}
419.586515381 {Some other data}
427.316825959 {Some other data}
.......
```

Each line starts off with a number and is followed by some other data. The numbers are in sorted order. I need to be able to:

1. Given a number `x` and and a range `y`, find all the lines whose number is within `y` range of `x`. For example if `x=20` and `y=5`, I need to find all lines whose number is between `15` and `25`.
2. Store these lines into another separate file.

What would be an efficient method to do this without having to trawl through the entire file?

Comment: Since you know the length of the file and the file is sorted, perhaps a variation of binary sort to find the row with the smallest value in your range, with a line by line read till you reach the max value?

Comment: It really helps that the data is sorted. What you could try is this: open a chunk of the file in memory, say a 512mb chunk. Then see what the last line number is. If it's bigger than your range, search that chunk for the precise line numbers, if not, load next chunk and repeat the check. This way you don't load the whole thing into memory, but when you do find a chunk, the work is done really fast in memory. You'd also need something solve the issue if your range spans multiple chunks, but that's doable. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Presumably, the lines are not all the same length?

Comment: yes the lines are not the same length.

Comment: You need to index the file, see my answer below for two possibilities.

Comment: @Loccsta -- Is there an approximate length of each line (order of magnitude estimate?)  Are the lines approximately equally spaced in in terms the distance `float(line2.split()[0]) - float(line.split([0])`?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to generate a database ahead of time for line lengths, you can try this:

```
import os
import sys

# Configuration, change these to suit your needs
maxRowOffset = 100  #increase this if some lines are being missed
fileName = 'longFile.txt'
x = 2000
y = 25

#seek to first character c before the current position
def seekTo(f,c):
    while f.read(1) != c:
        f.seek(-2,1)

def parseRow(row):
    return (int(row.split(None,1)[0]),row)

minRow = x - y
maxRow = x + y
step = os.path.getsize(fileName)/2.
with open(fileName,'r') as f:
    while True:
        f.seek(int(step),1)
        seekTo(f,'\n')
        row = parseRow(f.readline())
        if row[0] < minRow:
            if minRow - row[0] < maxRowOffset:
                with open('outputFile.txt','w') as fo:
                    for row in f:
                        row = parseRow(row)
                        if row[0] > maxRow:
                            sys.exit()
                        if row[0] >= minRow:
                            fo.write(row[1])
            else:
                step /= 2.
                step = step * -1 if step < 0 else step
        else:
            step /= 2.
            step = step * -1 if step > 0 else step
```

It starts by performing a binary search on the file until it is near (less than `maxRowOffset`) the row to find. Then it starts reading every line until it finds one that is greater than `x-y`. That line, and every line after it are written to an output file until a line is found that is greater than `x+y`, and which point the program exits.

I tested this on a 1,000,000 line file and it runs in 0.05 seconds. Compare this to reading every line which took 3.8 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

You need random access to the lines which you won't get with a text files unless the lines are all padded to the same length.

One solution is to dump the table into a database (such as SQLite) with two columns, one for the number and one for all the other data (assuming that the data is guaranteed to fit into whatever the maximum number of characters allowed in a single column in your database is).  Then index the number column and you're good to go.

Without a database, you could read through file one time and create an in-memory data structure with pairs of values showing containing (number, line-offset).  You calculate the line-offset by adding the lengths of each row (including line end).  Now you can binary search these value pairs on number and randomly access the lines in the file using the offset.  If you need to repeat the search later, pickle the in-memory structure and reload for later re-use.

This reads the entire file (which you said you don't want to do), but does so only once to build the index.  After that you can execute as many requests against the file as you want and they will be very fast.

Note that this second solution is essentially creating a database index on your text file.

Rough code to create the index in second solution:

```
 import Pickle

 line_end_length = len('\n') # must be a better way to do this!
 offset = 0
 index = [] # probably a better structure to use than a list

 f = open(filename)
 for row in f:
     nbr = float(row.split(' ')[0])
     index.append([nbr, offset])
     offset += len(row) + line_end_length

 Pickle.dump(index, open('filename.idx', 'wb')) # saves it for future use
```

Now, you can perform a binary search on the list.  There's probably a much better data structure to use for accruing the index values than a list, but I'd have to read up on the various collection types.

Comment: I am interested in this second method that you described. Do you have any example code for this?

Comment: I doubt that this approach is faster and uses less memory than the solution proposed by me below.

Comment: You could well be right -- I don't know unix command line tools.  Also, it depends on whether this is a once-off request or will be constantly repeated against a static file.  If the latter, this may be slower up front (to build the index) but I think it will be very fast (sub-one-second) on subsequent requests, especially if the index can be maintained in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to match the first field, you can use [`gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/):

```
$ gawk '{if ($1 >= 15 && $1 <= 25) { print }; if ($1 > 25) { exit }}' your_file
```

**Edit:** Taking a file with 261,775,557 lines that is 2.5 GiB big, searching for lines `50,010,015` to `50,010,025` this takes 27 seconds on my `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 860  @ 2.80GHz`. Sounds good enough for me.

Comment: Not line numbers, I think, the value at the front of each row.

Comment: I assume that qawk will, in fact, walk the entire file for each request?

Comment: I've added some example of how this approach performs.

Comment: Actually I need to search the file for several hundred numbers. I probably need a more efficient method like binary search.

Comment: The size of the file is the limiting number, not the number of lines you want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the line that starts with the number just above your lower limit, you have to go through the file line by line until you find that line. No other way, i.e. all data in the file has to be read and parsed for newline characters.

We have to run this search up to the first line that exceeds your upper limit and stop. Hence, it helps that the file is already sorted. This code will hopefully help:

```
with open(outpath) as outfile:
    with open(inpath) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            t = float(line.split()[0])
            if lower_limit <= t <= upper_limit:
                outfile.write(line)
            elif t > upper_limit:
                break
```

I think theoretically there is no other option.

Comment: may be incorrect: when first value of `t` that above `upper_limit` also above `upper_limit`. Replace `lower_limit <= t` to `lower_limit <= t < upper_limit`.

Comment: this is exactly what I dont want to do. Also the file is too large to be loaded into memory as a whole.

Comment: @Loccsta: Using this method, the file is not loaded into memory. This is a line-based approach (one line is read from the input file and either dropped or written to the output file. It's not saved in memory). Furthermore, I'd love to see how you want to find the first line fulfilling the criterion without searching for newline characters in the file :). Remember, your lines are not equal in length.

Comment: `you have to go through the file line by line` Not true, you can use file.seek() to jump around the file and could probably save a lot of time

Comment: @Matt: I agree that you could peek somewhere randomly, from there search the next or previous newline character, read the number and repeat that via the method of nested intervals. However, I believe this task is not worth inventing a specialized algorithm. It is important that we don't read the file into memory, that's all.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke He asked for an efficient way to do this. Reading every line is considerably slower than a binary search.